# How can I read the "attributedBody" column in macOS' iMessage database?

Tags: objective-c, macos, imessage, macos-ventura

Apple changed the Messages database schema in the latest macOS Ventura update, and sent messages seem to no longer store their body/content in the `text` column. The `attributedBody` column has the content, but it's stored as an encoded blob.

Has anyone had any luck getting plaintext out of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `attributedBody` column is a serialized `NSMutableAttributedString` — packed using `NSArchiver`. It can be unpacked and read using `NSUnarchiver` but must first be extracted from the Messages sqlite database without losing any of its non-printable characters.

To preserve the column's content when performing a query, you can use sqlite3's `HEX()` function. The resulting bytes can then be read back into their original state by iterating over them and building a new `NSString`.

---

In the example below, `NSData` is extended with two helper methods to handle reading a file with hex-encoded data. Using `dataWithContentsOfHexEncodedFile`, a message record's `attributedBody` can be passed to `NSUnarchiver`, which will handle decoding the serialized `NSAttributedString`. This can then be converted to a normal `NSString` by accessing the `string` property.

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@implementation NSData (NSDataExtended)
+ (NSData *)dataWithContentsOfHexEncodedString:(NSString *) string {
    const char * chars = [string UTF8String];
    int i = 0;
    
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: string.length / 2];
    char byteChars[3] = {'\0', '\0', '\0'};
    unsigned long wholeByte;
    
    while (i < string.length) {
        byteChars[0] = chars[i++];
        byteChars[1] = chars[i++];
        wholeByte = strtoul(byteChars, NULL, 16);
        [data appendBytes:&wholeByte length:1];
    }
    
    return data;
}

+ (NSData *)dataWithContentsOfHexEncodedFile:(NSString *) filePath {
    return [self dataWithContentsOfHexEncodedString:[NSString
                                    stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                    error:nil]];
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    system([[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s %s > %s",
             "/usr/bin/sqlite3 ~/Library/Messages/chat.db",
             "'SELECT HEX(attributedBody) FROM message ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 1'",
             "/private/tmp/msgbody"] UTF8String]);
    
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    NSMutableAttributedString *msg = [[[NSUnarchiver alloc]
                                       initForReadingWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfHexEncodedFile:@"/private/tmp/msgbody"]
                                      ] decodeTopLevelObjectAndReturnError:nil];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", [msg string]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is also a Python port of Apple's NSUnarchiver implementation: https://github.com/dgelessus/python-typedstream